# Is the size of stack allocated to every thread in a multi-threaded environment same?

Tags: computer-architecture, os

When OS allocates stack for every thread , what allocation scheme is used ? How does OS decides how much stack is required by a thread , is it decided at compile time itself ?

Please explain how the OS decides how much memory is required by a program in general ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not an EE question at all – OS design is clearly the domain of computer science, and not electronics design. Also, this is something that you'll find might not be solved in the same way everywhere, so the question might be ill-stated.

Comment: also, based on your history of StackOverflow questions: You have the tendency to ask about complicated things where you don't understand the basics. This might be another case of that. If you're wondering why most questions of you get a negative score: do more research on the topics you ask about to avoid asking a question in the wrong place, or confusing terms.

Comment: try your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer mostly depends on whether the CPU has a memory management unit. If one is present, then the OS is able to dynamically allocate memory to a thread/process as required until memory resources are exhausted. The thread/process has no idea of how physical memory is being allocated - it just believes it has access to the full address space, and the OS manages the physical backing of this virtual address space as required in the background.

If there is no memory management unit (such as on small embedded systems) then you would typically have to specify the amount of memory allocated for the stack in advance (either at compile time or when the thread is launched). You can even emulate, to some extent, the operation of a memory management unit if you want, but it quickly gets complicated. In practice, the stack on small embedded systems is usually quite small and well behaved (no big automatic structs/arrays, no recursion) so stack management is not that big an issue.